# How to hide a hide shadow from view in android?

Tags: java, android, view

Trying to put a view in front of some animation so it will cover part of it.

This is a sample of my code:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); // the background color
view.bringToFront();
view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
view.setZ(10); // -> this cause the shadow but i need it to cover the animation.
```

and this is the things I have tried to do in order to remove the shadow:

```
view.setPaddingRelative(0,0,0,0);
view.setElevation(0);
```

They didn't worked out.

in the link below is what i'm trying to get rid off:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1GFx.jpg

***note** : *I don't use XML for the view.*

Comment: Try using FrameLayout maybe?

Comment: I found some other solution for my problem but not for this question... I tried to hide some part of button so I just set his Z to -10 and then the view didn't have shadow on z=0.